# Module naming convention (avoid collisions)

Tags: python, module, naming-conventions

I'm learning Python and I have already created few ad-hoc utility modules that I use for whatever.  I don't intend to install them anywhere, having them simply laying around and copying them wherever needed is OK for me now.

So I typically just create a file named like `mymodule.py` and `import mymodule` from a script in the same directory.  For names I use lowercase alphabet (i.e. no `_`s)  only. So now after I have seen couple of "real" Python modules and realized that the convention is mostly the same, I'm starting to wonder about *clashes*.

Is there a convention for naming own ad-hoc modules, so that one can avoid clashes with core or "pip" modules (even future ones that are yet to be added)?

Similar convention [exists in Perl community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658955/how-do-i-choose-a-package-name-for-a-custom-perl-module-that-does-not-collide-wi) (especially because of CPAN), where all such modules should start with `Local::`, as in `Local::MyCrazyModule`.

*Note:* There is [a similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095188/is-there-a-python-naming-convention-for-avoiding-conflicts-with-standard-module), but that one does not seem to ask specifically about modules, but rather about variable names clashing with modules.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to not to conflict with pip modules is to create dump module with your name and publish it to pypi. And then you can use this top level namespace for all your modeles, the published or not published.

For more informations about name conversions you can read: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/

Comment: While I agree this might be the easiest solution, I really don't like the idea of everyone polluting pypi space with their names (think of all the `johnsmith`'s). Is that even allowed kn pypi?

Comment: ..that said, if in my mind I strip off the part about publishing, +1